# Function Notation with "|"

Tags: notation

What does that following notation mean in english?

[image]

In this case, J is a set, but I am not sure how the "|" relates the set to the function f.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the domain of the function, say the domain is the set $D$, is restricted to an smaller set $J \subset D$

Answer (score 1):

"$f|_J$" means "$f$ restricted to $J$".